# WPF DataGrid, application crash when adding a row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf datagrid bound to a TrackableCollection. In some rare occations, and for only a few selected users, the application will crash when the user adds a new record by entering the bottom blank row. 
I have not been able to reproduce the issue, and all I have is a stacktrace of the exception thrown.
Has anyone seen anything like this? I have limited knowledge about the automationpeer-classes, but I can confirm that we are not using any of them in our application.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer.CreateItemAutomationPeer(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ItemsControlAutomationPeer.FindOrCreateItemAutomationPeer(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer.RaiseAutomationSelectionEvents(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.MakeFullRowSelection(Object dataItem, Boolean allowsExtendSelect, Boolean allowsMinimalSelect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.HandleSelectionForCellInput(DataGridCell cell, Boolean startDragging, Boolean allowsExtendSelect, Boolean allowsMinimalSelect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="OrdreSLinjeGrid" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserAddRows="{Binding KanLeggeTilOrdreLinjer}"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Order.OrderLines, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserSortColumns="False"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ValgtOrdreLinje}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>           
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Header="{t:Translate Antall}" 
            TextAlignment="Right" 
            Width="50" 
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HøyrejustertColumnHeader}" 
            Binding="{Binding Antall, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="{t:Translate Pris}" 
            Width="60" 
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HøyrejustertColumnHeader}" 
            Binding="{Binding Pris, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
             />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Any input or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you also post the code around this logic where this exception occurs?

Comment: Is your grid bound to a specific property?  What does your xaml look like?  What does the property that is tied to the xaml?

Comment: @ryadavilli 
The exception doesn't occur in our code. It's something internally in the WPF DataGrid.

Comment: WPF data grid will not throw exceptions on its own. It will do so only if misused.  At the end of it all, it seems you are trying to assign a null value to some property which is used in your XAML. I would suggest debugging and figuring it out.

Comment: @DJ Burb
Edit: adding xaml in op.

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this? I recently ran into the problem on one of my machines, but not any others. Do you know which version(s) of .NET are installed on the machine with the problem?

Comment: For what it is worth, we had the same problem but only when the app was running on Win8 OR we turned the Narrator on in Win7. Ours turned out to be an difficult-to-debug interaction between various property setters. After the property was set, somewhere in that code we were setting it back to null. Before I diagnosed that, I found that the solution here 'fixed' the automation peer symptom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245732/nullreferenceexception-from-presentationframework-dll

Answer (score 10):

The problem is related to a bug in `DataGridAutomationPeer.RaiseAutomationSelectionEvents` internal method which simply speaking does not check if SelectedItem property is null or not. It can easily be reproduced by running "Microsoft Narrator" tool in Windows 7.

Because this is a sealed class there is no easy way to fix it except intercepting this method using Reflection.Emit or any mocking tool out there and even if it's fixed we have no guarantee that Microsoft won't change this method name, signature or behaviour.

I implemented a "good enough" fix by inheriting from DataGrid which will change the way DataGrid is unselected when the SelectedItem is null but only if narrator/touchscreen is present.

Hopefully the bug will be fixed soon. Add reference to UIAutomationProvider if necessary.

```
using System.Windows.Automation.Peers;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class TooDataGrid: DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.SelectionItemPatternOnElementSelected) ||
            AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.SelectionItemPatternOnElementAddedToSelection) ||
            AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.SelectionItemPatternOnElementRemovedFromSelection))
        {
            if(SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution prevents the crash. But it has the disadvantage that de-selection no longer works properly, because for the de-selection a null value is used. That means the item always stays selected if it was selected before. Thats why I like this solution more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256740/4424024

Answer (score 9):

I know this is pretty old, but there is a good solution to this problem that I came across. You can define a custom converter using the `IValueConverter` interface:

```
public class SelectedItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ?? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == null || value.GetType().Name == "NamedObject") ? null : value;
    }
}
```

This checks if the value is `null` and if it is, returns `DependecyProperty.UnsetValue`. As described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) (look at the method descriptions):

> A return value of DependencyProperty.UnsetValue indicates that the converter produced no value and that the binding uses the FallbackValue, if available, or the default value instead.

Returning this rather than `null` should fix the issue.

Comment: in the `Convert` method you wrote `return value != null ? DependencyObject.UnsetValue : value`, shouldn't it be: `return value == null ? DependencyObject.UnsetValue : value`

Comment: Thanks! You saved me hours.

Answer (score 2):

No need for converters or for using a derived class.
Just make sure that the property you are binding to for SelectedItem is initialized with DependencyProperty.UnsetValue. Do not set it to or leave it at the default of null.

The underlying bug should be fixed in the not-too-far future, btw:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/575165/vs-1604-ide-crash-argumentnullexception.html

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was using a Converter to ensure strong typing for my SelectedItem, which returned null when nothing was selected. I made it return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to check for nulls on your properties in your view model.  If the property is null, replace the null with a valid value like a 0 or a blank.

You could also do this using a Value Converter

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with touch screen only.
I had a WPF app that was working fine until I connected the touch screen that the app was built for.

This issue occur when the DataGrid selected item was bounded to an object that was null;

I resolved it this way:

The DataGrid Xaml had this line:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelItem}"
```

The XVVM looked like:

```
public MyViewModel SelItem
{

    get
    {
        if (m_selected == null)
             return new MyViewModel();
        else
             return m_selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It occurs on Datagrid when user double clicks first row in DataGrid (with only one row). This is occurs only on Sony laptop with touchscreen. Sony software adds checkboxes to every file in Winfows Explorer. I think this problem is related to the sony software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know - will it help somebody, as i'm newbie.

I had the same issue when i was doing this:

```
            collectionView = Application.Current.MainWindow.TryFindResource("InputElements") as CollectionViewSource;
            if (collectionView != null && collectionView.View != null) collectionView.View.Refresh();
```

Crash happened after adding some element in my DataGrid second time this way:

1. No elements in DataGrid
2. Adding element to DataGrid with changing element property "UseInDataGrid" = true;
3. Deleting element from DataGrid with changing element property "UseInDataGrid" = false;
4. Adding same element to DataGrid with changing element property "UseInDataGrid" = true;
   -> Crash!

My DataGrid ItemSource was binded to StaticResource CollectionViewSource , that was binded to ObservableCollection with elements.

And for my elements there was a PropertyChanged method, where i used method above (View.Refresh()) when some of properties was changed.

After changing some logic, i've made collection view to refresh without View.Refresh() and this issue gone.