# WFP app is crashing after clicking on an item in Grid View

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a desktop wpf app that is using a data grid.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns       ="False"
                  CanUserAddRows     ="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows  ="False" 
                  IsReadOnly         ="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding                      Path=Project.DownstreamBranchUnits.View}"
                  ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="DataGrid_ScrollChanged">
```

Sometimes (its not always easy to reproduce) if you click on a row, it crashes with the following stack trace:

```
Error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridItemAutomationPeer..ctor(Object item, DataGridAutomationPeer dataGridPeer)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer.CreateItemAutomationPeer(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ItemsControlAutomationPeer.FindOrCreateItemAutomationPeer(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer.RaiseAutomationSelectionEvents(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedInfos, List`1 selectedInfos)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection.EndUpdateSelectedItems()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector.EndUpdateSelectedItems()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.MakeFullRowSelection(ItemInfo info, Boolean allowsExtendSelect, Boolean allowsMinimalSelect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.HandleSelectionForCellInput(DataGridCell cell, Boolean startDragging, Boolean allowsExtendSelect, Boolean allowsMinimalSelect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at DiamondBuilderUI.App.Main()
Object: PresentationFramework
Function: Void .ctor(System.Object, System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer)
Extra data:
System.Object - null
```

We use .net version 4.6 
Each row in this grid consists of an image, and other columns with some text
Just to be clear, I am not adding any new rows. I just click on a row, and open a dialog box based on the selected element. 
Appreciate any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF DataGrid, application crash when adding a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352615/wpf-datagrid-application-crash-when-adding-a-row) (same constructor on top of call stack, probably same reason: selecteditem null)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with DataGrid.
I found the cause in setting for one cell Binding property UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus. When I have changed it to PropertyChanged, the exception throwing was gone.
Of course event throwing every symbol change is not the best choese, but it is better then exception throwing =).

This throw an exception (part of DataTemplate code for DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

This not (part of DataTemplate code for DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

May be you have the same issue.